# Post javascript module array as List object with ajax in asp .net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, jquery

I want to send JavaScript object array as list object to server, the server side method(GetData) accepts list object with 3 elements, but all elements have null value. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

**At Client:**

*User.js*

```
define(function () {        
    function User(name) {
        this.Name = name 
    }
    return User;
});
```

*main.js*

```
var users = [new User('Barney'),
                 new User('Cartman'),
                 new User('Sheldon')];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/GetData",
        data: {users: users},
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.Result);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

**At Server:**

*GetData action*

```
public void GetData(List<User> users){
}
```

*User Model*

```
public class User {
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the object returned by new `User('Barney')` is of the form `{ Name : "Barney"}` ? I tried replicating the example you gave me and it worked fine for me. Are there any other properties on User that you are not showing the example above?

Comment: Yes, alert(Json.stringify(new User('Barney'))) results as { "Name" : "Barney"}

Comment: Hi @frictionlesspulley can you share your replication? I can't know what is the difference without seeing yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed main.js like below, and it worked:

*main.js*

```
var params = {'users': [new User('Barney'),
                        new User('Cartman'),
                        new User('Sheldon')]};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/GetData",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.Result);
        },
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
```